# Error in submiting the data in database, how to solve this?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a page called `index.php` and inside that page I have a function for insertion, the insertion is working fine but my real problem is in a "select". Whenever I try to save the record in db it is successfully saving but in my "province" selection it saves the id. What I want is that it should save the name not the id number. Please somebody help me.

**Here is the code**

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
    {
    $Province = $_POST['Province'];
    $Location = $_POST['Location'];
    $Barangay = $_POST['Barangay'];

   if($crud->create($Province, $Location, $Barangay))
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Saved!');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Insertion Failed!'); </script>";
    }
}
?>

<body bgcolor="black">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="image/header.png" class="img-responsive">
            <div id="logout">
                <a href="logout.php?logout=true">Logout</a>
            </div><!--End of Div login-->       
        </div>
    </div>
<label class="Province">
    <span>Province</span>
    <select name="Province" class="province">
        <option selected="selected" value="">--Select Province--</option>
            <?php
                $stmt = $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT id,province_name FROM province");
                $stmt->execute();
                    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['province_name']; ?></option>
            <?php
                    } 
            ?>

     </select>
    </label>
```

**here is the code for the ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(".province").change(function()
    {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_state.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".municipality").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });


    $(".municipality").change(function()
    {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_city.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".barangay").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });
  });
```

**here the code for the get_state.php**

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM municipality WHERE province_id=:id");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
?><option selected="selected">Select State :</option><?php
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['municipality_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['municipality_name']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What SQL error do you get if you try the query using phpMyAdmin (for example)?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan there was no error..the insertion is fine but the problem is that when i view my db the data that is save under the "province" field is the id..it should be the province name

Comment: Then you should post your INSERT query and not your SELECT ^^

Comment: @Inceddy this is a dynamic selection.. and i'm using ajax let me update my code..

Comment: As @BenPearlKahan said, did you check your province table with phpMyAdmin or s.th. similar?

Comment: If code seems ok, and if it's weird that you get something else under `province_name` - why would you post your JS code and HTML and not log onto your MySQL and see for yourself what's stored in the table? You assumed everything is fine and dandy in the db and now you're forcing a debug on some piece of code that looks fine.

Comment: This is because the `value` of your `option` is the ID I'd have thought.

Comment: @Inceddy i already check it and is fine..my only problem is that,when i save the records it is working fine but when i checked it in my phpmyadmin it shows in the province filed the id corresponding to them province name

Comment: @JoeP yeah i know that,but when i tried to change that in "province_name" the other select function is not working..beacause this is a dynamic dropdown

Comment: Being dynamic doesn't really have anything to do with the problem you're getting.  You need to post your `UPDATE` code, because that's where the problem lies, or some processing involved before it.
From what I can see you are only passing `id=id` to your `get_state.php` page.

Comment: @JoeP so what do i need to do now?

Comment: @JoeP i already updated my code

Comment: If the update it working but is just getting the ID instead, then I'd have though just changing to `<option value="<?php echo $row['province_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['province_name']; ?></option>`
However, this depends if you need to pass the ID to parse the data or not, in which case you'd need to post the actual update sql, and what file this happens in.

Comment: @Joep i already done that but its still its not working..when i try to do that the province displaying the options but in municipality there's nothing is displayed

Comment: @JoeP can you please help me with it..or maybe can you give me sample code for the dynamic dropdown?

Comment: Well I can't diagnose that because you've not posted the code, I'd assume that it's probably because you're doing your next lookup based on the ID, but you'd need to change it to be looking for the province_name value instead

Comment: @JoeP let me update my code

Answer (score 2):

First of all use JSON. Thats better coding practice because you should not mixup html and PHP (or use a template-engine like twig!)

Your ajax.php:

```
<?php

/** Setup your DB-connection here **/

switch ($_GET['type']) {
    case 'province':
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT id, province_name FROM province");
        $stmt->execute();
        break;
    case 'municipal':
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM municipality WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
        break;

    default: 
        die('Error');
}

$response = array();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $response[] = $row;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Your JS:

```
function updateSelect(select, data) { 
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'url/to/ajax.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            select.empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, row){
                select.append($('option').attr({value: row.id}).html(row.name));
            });
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Better use id than class
    $('#province').change(function(){
        updateSelect($('#municipality'), {id: $(this).val(), type : 'municipal'})
    });
}
```

This code is untested. Just'n rough idea how to solve this.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i don't have any idea on how to put that in my code

Comment: But you understand what it's doing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a matter of simple HTML code.
You have a select with value = the id of the province and that display the province name as option. When you post this form you are posting the value attribute of the option and this is what you will put into the db.
This is your line of code:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['province_name']; ?></option>
```

If you want to store the province name change it to:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['province_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['province_name']; ?></option>
```

Anyway I prefer to store code for this values and retrieve the name with a join if necessary. If you also need to keep the other select working dinamically you can add a `data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"` to each option that will become

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['province_name']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['province_name']; ?></option>
```

and in your javascript when you refer to :

```
var id=$(this).val(); //for the province only, so the first one
```

you change it to

```
var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
```

Comment: i have tried your code but now the problem is that when i select a province, the state is now displaying

Comment: What do you mean? The code behavior hasn't changed!